# Equivalent conditions for two functions to be equal almost everywhere in terms of integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

My question is.... if two measurable functions $f$ and $g$ on a measure space $(X, M, \mu)$ are such that for all $A \in M$,
$$
\int_{A}f\,d\mu = \int_{A}g\,d\mu,
$$
does this imply that $f=g$ a.e. $\mu?$ If this isn't true, then are there any restrictions we can impose (positivity or $\sigma$-finiteness of $\mu$, etc.) to salvage the statement?

I've tried defining $E$ to be the set such that $f \neq g$ and show that it must have measure zero, but I can't find the right manipulations of the integral expressions to squeeze that out.... any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Yeah, so for the $A = [0,1]$ example, the integral of your $f$ and $g$ are the same over *all* of $A$, but not over all subsets of it. That is the assumption I am making.

Answer (score 9):

Let $$A_\epsilon=\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{{#1}\right\}}\set{x\in X: f(x) \ge g(x)+\epsilon},$$
which is measurable because $f$ and $g$ are. 
Observe that $$0=\int_{A_\epsilon} f-g \,d\mu \ge \epsilon \mu(A_\epsilon),$$
so $\mu(A_\epsilon)=0$ for all $\epsilon$. Can you finish the proof from here?

Comment: Ah, ok, so then you mirror the argument for a set where $g(x) \geq f(x) + \epsilon$ to show it must have measure zero, as well. And then since it holds for all $\epsilon$, it must be the case that the set $\{x \in X : f(x) \neq g(x) \}$ must have measure zero. I can rigorize this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user69690, yep, tho I think you mean $\set{x\in X : f(x)\ne g(x)}$ has measure zero.

Comment: Yup; sorry--my bad :)

Comment: Sorry could you explain me why the integral is $0$?

Comment: @user123234 because the integrals of the functions are equal on all measurable subsets, so the integral of the difference is zero on all measurable subsets.

Answer (score 1):

Lemma: Suppose $\mu(C)>0$ and $h(x)>0$ for every $x\in C.$ Then $\displaystyle \int_C h\,d\mu>0.$

To prove this, consider the inverse-images under $h$ of $[1/(n+1),\, 1/n)$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots\,.$ At least one of them has positive measure and you get a positive lower bound

Let $A=\{x\in X : f(x)>g(x)\}$ and $B=\{x\in X: f(x)< g(x)\}.$

By the Lemma, if $\mu(A)>0$ then $\displaystyle \int_A f\, d\mu > \int_A g\,d\mu.$ If $\mu(B)>0$ then $\displaystyle \int_B f\,d\mu < \int_B g\, d\mu.$

So if $\displaystyle\int_C f\,d\mu = \int_C g\,d\mu$ for every measurable set $C$, then $\mu(A) = \mu(B)=0,$ so $f=g$ almost everywhere.