# Expected Value for mutually independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be random variables. Show that if for any functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$  $\beta_1, ... , \beta_n$, that
$$E[\beta_1(X_1) \times ... \times \beta_n(X_n)] = E[\beta_1(X_1)] \times ... \times E[\beta_n(X_n)] \implies X_1, ..., X_n \text{ are mutually independent} $$

---

This is where I'm at with the question so far:

From the definition of the probability density function and mutual in-dependency, we have that
$$X_1, ..., X_n \text{ are mutually independent} \iff f_{X_1, ..., X_n}(x_1, ..., x_n) = f_{X_1}(x_1) \times ... \times f_{X_n}(x_n) $$
And by the definition of expected value:
$$E[\beta_1(X_1) \times ... \times \beta_n(X_n)] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} ... \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\beta_1(x_1)... \beta_n(x_n)f_{X_1, ..., X_n}(x_1, ... x_n)dx_1 ... dn_x$$
$$E[\beta_1(X_1)] \times ... \times E[\beta_n(X_n)] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\beta_1(x_1)f_{X_1}(x_1)dx_1 ... \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\beta_n(x_n)f_{X_n}(x_n)dx_n$$
Somehow I need to show that those two expected values above implies $f_{X_1, ..., X_n}(x_1, ..., x_n) = f_{X_1}(x_1) \times ... \times f_{X_n}(x_n)$, but I'm not really sure how to do so.

Comment: I think you'll want to consider the case where $(\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n)$ is an indicator function on a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, so that $E(\beta_1(X_1) \times \cdots \times \beta_n(X_n))$ should just be $P((X_1,\ldots,X_n) \in A)$.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer I was able to figure out the proof if $\beta_1, ... \beta_n$ were indicator functions for the support of $X_1, ..., X_n$, but I'm not sure how to generalize it for arbitrary functions. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity consider the case $n = 2$ (the general case goes the same). Let $\beta_1$ be the indicator function on some interval $[x_1,x_2]$ and $\beta_2$ the indicator function on $[y_1,y_2]$. Then
$$E(\beta_1 X_1 \times \beta_2 X_2) = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \int_{y_1}^{y_2} f_{1,2}(x,y) \,dx\,dy$$
whereas
$$E(\beta_1 X_1) \times E(\beta_2 X_2) = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \int_{y_1}^{y_2} f_1(x)\,f_2(y) \,dx\,dy$$
So what we see is that we have two functions in $2$ variables, namely $f_{1,2}(x,y)$ and $f_1(x)\,f_2(y)$, whose double integrals are the same on every square.

I claim that this is sufficient to conclude that $f_{1,2}(x,y) = f_1(x) \,f_2(y)$ almost everywhere (i.e. everywhere if your functions are continuous). If your functions are continuous, you can make the following argument. Suppose that at some point $(x,y)$ they differ, say $f_{1,2}(x,y) < f_1(x) \,f_2(y)$, then this inequality remains true on a small neighbourhood of $(x,y)$, and we can just choose our square sufficiently small to ensure that the two integrals are unequal as well. But more generally, the conclusion remains valid if the functions are merely measurable, see e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2869403/874176).

Comment: Thank you for answering! I follow your argument and it makes sense to me, however, a couple questions. How does this answer apply to any function in which the expected value exists, not just indicators of sets. For instance, if $\beta_1 = x^2$. I made [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4013889/expected-value-of-random-variables-with-arbitrary-functions) attempting to use your previous comment, is there a way to do this question in the same fashion?

Comment: Once you know the equality in the case that the $\beta_i$ are indicator functions, you have enough to infer independence. From independence, you can then conversely infer that in fact the equality holds for *all* $\beta_i$.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't realize that! That makes sense then, thank you!